# Migration to rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am migrating a rails 2.3.5 project to rails 3.

I get a lot of errors in the lines when i am using:

```
params[:something]
```

that i have to change ti with:

```
request.path_parameters[:something]
```

It this right? I am unable to found something about this in rails3 migration guides.

My controller:

```
def details
foo=Tag.find(params[:id])
end
```

and i get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Couldn't find Tag without an ID
```

Comment: Can you post an example of some failing code?

Comment: params[:id] works fine with Rails 3

Comment: I added details editing the question

Comment: Could be an issue with your route, can you post your routes.rb?

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the ":" in params[:id].

That may be the reason you're receiving the error.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from your error, which is probably due to the missing : as tapioco123 pointed out, are you using the rails_upgrade plugin?

https://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade

There are also three excellent screencasts by Ryan Bates at railscasts on upgrading from rails 2.3.5 to 3.0.

http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=upgrading+rails+3

This will help you switch over to some of the new features rails 3 offers and prepare you for rails 3.1 which is expected to be released soon and may not show all the depreciation messages that rails 3.0 will.

Good luck with upgrading.